# Why do Maybe/Optional types use a Just/Some type instead of the actual type?

Tags: haskell, types, ml, idris, option-type

In Idris, the `Maybe` type is defined as followed:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

It's defined similarly in Haskell:

```
 data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
     deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

Here's the ML version:

```
datatype 'a option = NONE | SOME of 'a
```

What are the benefits of using `Just` and `Some`?
Why not define the type without them?

example:

```
data Maybe a = a | Nothing
```

Comment: `data Maybe a = a | Nothing` is not valid Haskell—it won’t compile. That definition would effectively imply `Maybe a` is a *union* of any value or `Nothing`, but that’s pretty useless, since `Nothing` is also “any value”. (Haskell’s type system doesn’t support untagged unions like this at all, since that would require some notion of “subtyping”, which Haskell does not have.)

Comment: No, `Maybe a` would be a union of `a` or `Nothing`, and `Nothing` would normally not be a value of type `a`, so a type like `Maybe Int` wouldn't be useless. Correct that Haskell doesn't support this though.

Answer (score 26):

What would then be the difference between

```
Maybe a
```

and

```
Maybe (Maybe a)
```

?

There's supposed to be a difference between `Nothing` and `Just Nothing`.

Comment: For some reason, I am amused whenever I find that I have to type `pure Nothing` :).

Comment: But why is there supposed to be a difference?

Comment: @Reid Because applying `Maybe` to a type creates a new type with one additional value. This means that applying it twice should create a new type with two additional values.

Comment: This is not a joke, in my experience, `Just Nothing` occurs not too often, but from time to time it does.

Comment: Of course the semantics of Haskell (and Idris etc.) say that `Nothing` and `Just Nothing` are different, but this is just pushing back the question.

Comment: And it's entirely reasonable to consider failure sooner the same as failure later, if you consider failure a computational effect (and have no other observables that happen before the failure).

Comment: This comes up in the book [Land of Lisp](https://books.google.is/books?id=9apQfCRhvm0C&lpg=PA62&dq=%22land%20of%20lisp%22%20%22nil%22%20%20tear&hl=is&pg=PA61#v=onepage&q&f=false): `(find-if #'null '(2 4 nil 6))` correctly returns the element satisfying the `null` predicate (`nil`) but this is the same result if no elements had satisfied the predicate! Haskell is much clearer: `find (== Nothing) [Just 2, Just 4, Nothing, Just 6]` succeeds with `Just Nothing` (because it found the `Nothing` in the list) but `find (== Nothing) [Just 2, Just 4, Just 6]` fails with `Nothing`.

Comment: @Ingo it happens more often than you think, when using abstractions that you never thought would use `Maybe` inside

Answer (score 11):

The key problem of allowing any value to be `null` (the "billion-dollar mistake") is that interfaces receiving a value of a type `T` have no way to declare whether or not they can handle a `null`, and interfaces that provide one have no way to declare whether or not they might produce `null`. This means that **all** of the operations that are usable on `T` essentially "might not work" when you pass them a `T`, which is a pretty gaping hole in all of the guarantees supposedly provided by compile-time type-checks.

The Maybe/Optional solution to this is to say that the type `T` **does not contain** a `null` value (in languages that had this from the beginning, that's literal; in languages adopting an Optional type later without removing support for `null`, then that's only a convention that requires discipline). So now all of the operations whose type says they accept a `T` **should** work when I pass them a `T`, regardless of where I got the `T` (if you haven't managed to design to "make illegal states unrepresentable" then there will of course be other reasons why an object can be in an invalid state and cause failure, but at least when you pass a `T` there'll actually be *something* there).

Sometimes we do need a value that can be "either a `T` or nothing". It's **such** a common case that pervasive `null` seemed like a good idea at the time, after all. Enter the `Maybe T` type. But to avoid falling back into exactly the same old trap, where I get a possibly-null `T` value and pass it to something that can't handle `null`, we need that **none of the operations on `T` can be used on a `Maybe T` directly**. Getting a type error from trying to do that is the entire point of the exercise. So my `T` values can't be directly members of `Maybe T`; I need to wrap them up *inside* a `Maybe T`, so that if I have a `Maybe T` I'm forced to write code that handles *both* cases (and only in the case for actually having a `T` can I call operations that work on `T`).

Whether this makes a word like `Just` or `Some` appear in the source code, and whether or not this is actually implemented with additional boxing/indirection in memory (some languages do represent a `Maybe T` as a nullable pointer to `T` internally), all of that is irrelevant. But the `Just a` case **must** be different from simply having an `a` value.

Comment: This argument falls apart somewhere near the end, since languages with subtyping can have real optional (or more generally, union) types. You argue that `T` and `Maybe T` must be different, but it doesn't follow that a value of type `T` can't also have type `Maybe T`.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure it is correct to speak of "benefits" in this context. What you have here is just a consequence of the way types are implemented in Haskell and ML - basically, Hindley-Milner algebraic type system. This type system essentially assumes that every value belongs to a *single* type (putting aside Haskell's numeric tower and bottom, which are outside of this discussion.) In other words, there is no *subtyping*, and that's for a reason - otherwise the type inference would be undecidable.

When you define type `Maybe a` what you want is to *adjoin* a single additional value to the type denoted by `a`. But you can't do it directly - if you could then every value of `a` would belong to two different types - the original `a` and `Maybe a`. Instead, what is done is `a` is *embedded* in a new type - you have a canonical injection `a -> Just a`. In other words, `Maybe a` is isomorphic to a union of `a` and `Nothing` which you can't represent directly in HM type system.

So I don't think that arguments along the lines that such a distinction is beneficial are valid - you can't have a system without it which is still ML or Haskell or any familiar HM-based system.

Comment: Is Haskell type inference decidable?

Comment: To paraphrase *The hitchhiker's guide*, mostly decidable.

Comment: The prosecution rests.

Comment: @augustss Usually, I mean what GHC will do in a few years' time, but today, polymorphic recursion will do fine.

Comment: But Haskell type "inference" for polymorphic recursion is decidable, since you have to give a type signature. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if `Maybe` was defined the way you propose, i.e. `data Maybe a = a | Nothing` there would be no way to differentiate `a` values from `Maybe a` values (and `Maybe (Maybe a)` for that matter).

So you may ask, why do we need to have such a distinction? What are the benefits? To give you a concrete example, suppose that we have a SQL table with a `integer NOT NULL` column. We would represent that with an `Int` in haskell. Now if we later on changed the database schema to make the column optional by dropping the `NOT NULL` constraint, we would have to change the haskell representation of the column to `Maybe Int`. The clear distinction between `Int` and `Maybe Int` would make it very easy to refactor our haskell code to account for the new schema. The compiler would complain for things such as extracting a value from the db and treating it as an `Int` (it might not be an integer, it might be `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of the constructor (`Just` or `Some`) is that it provides a way to distinguish between the branches of the data type. That is, it avoids ambiguity.

For example if we were relying on type inference, then the type of x in the following seems fairly straightforward — `String`.

```
x = "Hello"
```

However, if we allowed your definition of `Maybe`, how would we know whether `x` was `String`, a `Maybe String` or a `Maybe (Maybe String)` etc.

Also consider a data type with more than two cases:

```
data Tree a
  = Empty
  | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
  | Leaf a
```

If we simply removed the constructors (other than `Empty`), following your suggestion for `Maybe`, we'd end up with:

```
data Tree a
  = Empty
  | (Tree a) (Tree a)
  | a
```

I hope you can see that the ambiguity gets even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this *somewhat* equivalent of Maybe in C++/Java'ish psuedocode...

```
template<class T>
abstract class Maybe<T> { ... }

template<class T>
class Just<T> : Maybe<T> {
    // constructor
    Just<T> (T val) { ... }

    ...
}

template<class T>
class Nothing<T> : Maybe<T> {
    // constructor
    Nothing () { ... }

    ...
}
```

That is not specific to Maybe, it can be applied to any ADT. Now what exactly will

```
data Maybe a = a | Nothing
```

model into ? (assuming that its legal syntax).

If you were to write a switch statement, to 'pattern match' against types, what will u match against (the switch is on the TYPE not the value), something like this (not necessarily valid code) :

```
switch (typeof (x)) {
    case Just<a> : ...
    case Nothing<a> : ...
    default : ... // Here you dont have any 'a' to get the inner type
}
```